# Is it still a bad practice to store sensitive informations in an AES256 encrypted session cookie?

Tags: javascript, session, session-cookies

I'm currently designing a system of nodes that should obtain user data in seconds. It's nodejs based, so for this purpose I looked into the client-sessions npm module [provided by mozilla](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions). I see no warning about putting sensitive data in the cookie-session, at least from the documentation.

> The AES-256-CBC cipher is used to encrypt the session contents, with
>   an HMAC-SHA-256 authentication tag (via Encrypt-then-Mac composition).
>   A random 128-bit Initialization Vector (IV) is generated for each
>   encryption operation (this is the AES block size regardless of the key
>   size). The CBC-mode input is padded with the usual PKCS#5 scheme.

Years ago I would have say it is unbelievable. But now it looks like the paradigm has changed. What do you think SO?

Comment: Why are you storing sensitive data on the client side? Wouldn't it be better to keep it all on the server side?

Comment: For my project it would be ideal to store user data client side, because of node replication that would increase the complexity of sharing server-side-session-data between nodes.

Comment: With the secret still been server-side, and the cookie is only for client-side storage, this should be fine.  If you had client-side code injected to decode this, then it would not be secure.

Comment: data are a full LDAP record of the user

Comment: Well, you normally keep that data in some shared database, e.g. Redis. It is actually very simple to setup even sharded database if needed (Redis does support sharding out of the box now), since this is a simple `key: value` case. And this is a lot safer. Especially if you keep password inside this LDAP record.